# How does the window.requestAnimationFrame() work?

Tags: javascript

How can I understand the following code? I'm kind of new on JavaScript.

```
var start = null;
var element = document.getElementById('SomeElementYouWantToAnimate');
element.style.position = 'absolute';

function step(timestamp) {
   if (!start) start = timestamp;
      var progress = timestamp - start;
      element.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, 200) + 'px';
   if (progress < 2000) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
   }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

i get this piece of code here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

what I want to ask is about the `timestamp` parameters on the `function step(timestamp) {...}`.

I do not understand how this `timestamp` get the value, and why ? 
because I don't see any value assigned.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` will call the passed callback and will pass in the current time.

Comment: From the documentation you linked: `A parameter specifying a function to call when it's time to update your animation for the next repaint. The callback has one single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time (the time returned from performance.now() ) for when requestAnimationFrame() starts to fire callbacks.`

Comment: It's a parameter. It gets its value from the arguments, where the function is called - inside the `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: @Bergi don't think the op understands that rAF will automatically pass that to the callback function.

Comment: *"I do not understand how this timestamp get the value, and why ?"* The same way any function gets its parameter values: It's provided by the caller of the function, which is internal to the browser.

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you sir .. 
I feel lil embarrassed because you have to `highlight` something that I've been read before .. 
but everything is not so easy for me to figure this out sir .. I hope you understand .. and once again, thank you soo much

Comment: Nitpicking and maybe adding some confusions to OP, but rAF will stack the callbacks in a pool. When the time to fire will come, the internal executor will get the timestamp, then call all the callbacks in the pool passing them the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `requestAnimationFrame` function is something that looks vaguely like this:

```
function requestAnimationFrame(func) {
    waitForNextAnimationFrame();
    func(getCurrentTime());
}
```

What's happening is that the `requestAnimationFrame` is taking your function as an input, and then, later, calling it with an argument.